# Download button in gitbook leads to 404 page not found

Tags: r, github, bookdown, gitbook

I have a simple bookdown project that is producing both a gitbook and pdf versions of the output. Locally, both work, the output goes to docs, and when I click the download button in the browser I get the pdf version.

When I push to GitHub and set the project pages up to show the docs folder, the gitbook version is there and working fine. However clicking the download pdf button gives a 404 page not found error, and trying to get the pdf directly by appending the filename to the URL doesn't work either. The file _main.pdf is in the docs folder in the repo.

I'm currently specifying the download option in _output.yml as

`bookdown::gitbook:
  number_sections: no
  config:
    download: null`

I've tried various other options in there (filename, just the extension, leaving out the download option altogether), and nothing changes.

The book [is here](https://atyre2.github.io/vet-obserror/) and the GitHub repo is https://github.com/atyre2/vet-obserror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your website is not built with Github Pages, you must present a `.nojekyll` file (see [bookdown's documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/github.html)).

If it still does not work, it might be a bug of Github Pages to me (files with names starting with underscores are not well supported for some reason). In your [_bookdown.yml](https://github.com/atyre2/vet-obserror/blob/master/_bookdown.yml), you can add an option to change the filename, e.g. `book_filename: "vet-obserror"`.